# ArcSDE database connection strings for ArcCatalog

Tags: arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, arccatalog

Anyone know where the Database Connection strings are located in Program Files for ArcCatalog?  I have all my Database Connection strings fixed and all my scripts use them.  My computer went down and I have a chance to grab files off the hard drive.  Instead of me re-creating all my database connections..I think I've seen a .txt file that has the connection parameters and connection string names.  I figure this would be under C:\Program Files\ArcGIS....some where here.... but I can't find them.  Anyone know?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its under your user profile, AppData\Esri\ArcCatalog folder, it varies a little from 9.3.x and 10, but that should get you to the main location. Just look for the .sde files.

Answer (score 2):

I see two locations that mine are in. Not sure of the diff...

C:\Documents and Settings\myname\Application Data\ESRI\ArcCatalog

C:\Documents and Settings\bnesom\Application Data\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcCatalog

Comment: Your first one should be your older 9.3.x folder, the second is the 10. I couldn't look at mine exactly cause I have huge processing running.